# replace subset fonts in PDF using iText

Tags: pdf, fonts, itext, subset

Is it possible to replace subset embedded fonts by non-subset embedded fonts in PDF by any mechanism (for example using iText)?

The goal is to write some java routine which will takes an input PDF with subset fonts and outputs a PDF with fully embedded fonts, with a full copy of the entire character set of a fonts are stored in the PDF.

Any advice would have helped me a lot.

Comment: It depends on how the subsets of the fonts are embedded. For instance: if they are embedded as simple fonts, the subset can have a maximum of 256 characters. Most fonts have more characters, so in that case, you are out of luck. If your font is embedded as a composite font, you can store more characters, but even then it's tricky business because you can get the mapping between characters and the glyphs all wrong. It wouldn't recommend replacing an embedded subset by an embedded font. I can't think of a use case that would justify the work.

Comment: Bruno Lowagie: hi, thanks for your replay. The goal of doing this is because i'm decomposing PDFs and saving resources (fonts and graphics) into database and then link to them. With this logic i'm able to save the resource just once and refers to him when composing pdf again. With subset in input i have to save every subset fonts (each of them is unique).

Comment: In the trade-off "save storage space" versus "annoy people with bloated PDFs", I would choose not to annoy people with bloated PDFs and buy extra storage space. What you are doing goes against best practices in PDF. The documents you store won't be PDF/A documents (and PDF/A or ISO-19005 is the standard for archiving).

Comment: @Fleky What kind of PDFs are you trying to process? If their origins are uncontrolled, you shouldn't waste your time on that project. There simply are too many ways for completely valid PDFs to leave your process severely mutilated.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, more a general tools question, so you really want to ask this on [superuser](http://superuser.com) instead. And, as it turns out, someone already did: have a look at http://superuser.com/questions/166024/substitute-a-font-in-a-pdf-document

Comment: I you need a use case I can provide one : post-processing to replacea client name "placeholder" by the real name of the client